# How to iterate over mixed interface implementation array?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I have the following classes.

```
interface interface1() {
    void function1()
}
```

```
interface interface2 extends interface1() {
    void function2()
}
```

```
class implementation1 implements interface1 () {
    @Override
    void function1() {
        // Implement
    }
}
```

```
class implementation2 implements interface2 () {
    @Override
    void function1() {
        // Implement
    }

    @Override
    void function2() {
        // Implement
    }
}
```

```
class Main() {
    List<interface1> interfaceList = new ArrayList();
    for (interface : interfaceList) {
        if (interface instanceOf(interface2)) {
            interface.function2();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please tell if there is a way to prevent using instanceOf? I read visitor pattern could be used but I am not getting the exact changes to be done.

Following are the classes after discussing with Alex R below (instanceOf is avoided since it is not recommended, visitor pattern is avoided since it still leads to empty visit functions). Please let me know if this can be done better using other design patterns.

```
interface interface1() {
    void function1();

    boolean isFunction2Applicable();
    
    default void function2() {
    }
}
```

```
class implementation1 implements interface1 () {
    @Override
    void function1() {
        // Implement
    }

    @Override
    boolean isFunction2Applicable() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
class implementation2 implements interface1 () {
    @Override
    void function1() {
        // Implement
    }

    @Override
    boolean isFunction2Applicable() {
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    void function2() {
        // Implement
    }
}
```

```
class Main() {
    List<interface1> interfaceList = new ArrayList();
    for (interface : interfaceList) {
        if (interface.isFunction2Applicable()) {
            interface.function2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, double-dispatch (aka visitor pattern). Apart from that, not much you can do until Java supports pattern matching on the type (which is a "hidden" instanceof check)

Comment: Could you please give the pseudocode for using visitor pattern? In the examples I have seen, it is added for all implementations which is not useful in my case.

Comment: That's how the visitor pattern is implemented: the visitor needs to handle all types via `visit` methods and all types need to implement an `accept` method. See <https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor>

Comment: Are you saying I will add `accept(Visitor visitor)` to  interface1? This would lead to implementing `accept(Visitor visitor)` in implementation1 where this visitor is not applicable and related empty visit function right?

Comment: Do you really need `isFunction2Applicable`? You could call `function2` directly without that check: If the object is an instance of `interface1` only, the call to `function2` won't do anything since the method body is empty. Of course, implementations might override that behavior (after all it's just a default method) so whether you need want that check depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is to define some method in the base interface and override it in the sub-interfaces or implementations. In the following example I'm using a `default` method but you don't have to do so; the method can be abstract and only be implemented in the implementations:

```java
interface I1 {
    void function1();

    default void execute() {
        function1();
    }
}

interface I2 extends I1 {
    void function2();

    @Override
    default void execute() {
        function1();
        function2();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<I1> ifaces = new ArrayList<>();

    for (I1 iface : ifaces) {
        iface.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please tell if I can iterate and call function2() alone which is only there in interface2 and implementation2 (edited question also)?

Comment: @GopikrishnaKS Please lay out your requirements in more detail in your question. Your change has changed the question quite a lot from my perspective. In general there is no shame in using `instanceof` if these checks are not all over the place. The visitor-pattern is quite heavy-weight and if what your example shows is the only thing you need to do, using `instanceof` is fine, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to iterate over the general interface1 objects and call function2 wherever it is applicable. I thought using instance of is not recommended and since using visitor pattern would result in empty visit functions, instead to have a function isFunction2Applicable added in the merged interface that could be checked while iterating so that the implementation1 can have it as false and implementation2 can have it as true. This would still require empty function for function2 in implementation2 but hope this is not a major issue and this is the best option in this case.

Comment: @GopikrishnaKS Then, how about defining both functions in the base interface but making `function2` a `default` method with an empty body? Is that an option for you? In that case, you might also get rid of `interface2` entirely.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question to include the answer according to our discussion, could you please tell if there is a better way for this or this is fine?